# Ways to detect if any other threads exist (e.g. prior to fork)

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, fork

Background, [from POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):

> A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded process calls fork(), the new process shall contain a replica of the calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to avoid errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the exec functions is called.

The difficulty is that we generally don't *know* if we're a multi-threaded process, since threads may have been created by library code. And "async-signal-safe" is a quite-severe restriction.

It is nonsensical to ask "how many threads are there", since if other threads are still running, they may be exiting or creating new threads while asking. We can, however, get answers (or partial answers) to simpler questions:

1. Is it even possible for other threads to exist?
2. Am I the only thread that ever existed?
3. Am I the only thread that exists right now?
4. ...

For simplicity's sake let's assume:

- we're not in a signal handler
- nobody is mad enough to invoke UB by calling `pthread_create` or C11's `thrd_create` from a signal handler
- nobody is doing threads outside of pthreads, C11, and C++11

  - C++11 threads appear to always be implemented in terms of pthreads (on platforms that support fork, at least)
  - C11 threads are very similar to pthreads, although we sometimes have to handle the functions separately.

Answers that involve arcane implementation details are encouraged, as long as they are (fairly) stable.

Comment: I have some bad news. On Mac OSX, the standard library starts background threads.

Comment: If you're using implementation-specific functions to check for other threads, then you may be on an implementation that provides additional guarantees as to whether the library creates threads, or what you can do after `fork()` when multiple threads exist.

Answer (score 0):

Some partial answers (more still needed):

Question 1 is addressed by libstdc++'s `__gthread_active_p()` for several libc implementations. The header is compatible with C, but it a `static` function in a C++-only part of the include path, and also relies on the existence of macro `__GXX_WEAK__` which is only predefined for C++. (libc++ unconditionally pulls in pthreads)

Unfortunately, this is dangerously unreliable for the `dlopen` case (race conditions in correct user code), see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78017

Question 2 can be addressed by installing interceptors for `pthread_create` and `thrd_creat`. But this can *potentially* be finicky (see comments in `gthr.h` about interceptors).

If calling `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` and `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` differs, this may be proof that another thread has existed, but beware of races, resolution, and clock settability (setting these clocks is not possible on Linux, but POSIX potentially allows it)

Question 3 is the interesting one, anyway:

GDB is likely to know the answer, but spawning a whole other process seems unnecessary (e.g. answers involving ps should be rewritten to use `/proc/` directly)), and it may not have permission anyway

`libthread_db.so` exists but appears undocumented except in the original Solaris version. It looks like it *might* be possible to implement the `proc_service.h` callbacks for the current process however, if we ignore the "stop" part ...

On Linux, if `gettid() != getpid()`, you're not the main thread, thus there probably are at least two threads. (it's possible for the main thread to call `pthread_exit`, but this is weird)

A (somewhat) more portable version of the preceding: use `__attribute__((constructor))` (or politely ask your caller) to stash the value of `pthread_self()` for the main thread. Unfortunately, there is a disturbing comment in libstdc++'s `<thread>` header (grep for `__GLIBC__`) about returning 0 (but I cannot reproduce this).

On Linux if `/proc` is mounted and accessible, you can enumerate `/proc/self/task/`. The code to do this is portable, it will just fail on OSes that don't provide this. (are there others that do provide this much?). Is `/proc/self/status` or `/proc/self/stat` any more portable? They have less information (and `stat` is hard to parse securely), but we probably don't need any more. (need to test these for the "main thread exited" case)

On GLIBC, we could possibly read the debug symbols to find the `multiple_threads` flag (sometimes global, sometimes part of `struct pthread` - ugh). But this is probably similar to `libthread_db.so`

Similarly MUSL has a count (minus one) and a linked list ... though it prefers to take an internal lock first. If we're only reading, is it safe to skip that?

If we block a signal and then kill the current process (*not* thread) with it, and our thread isn't the one that receives it, we know that other threads must exist to handle it. But there's no way to know how long to wait, and signals are dangerous global state anyway.

On Linux, `unshare(2)` ignores `CLONE_THREAD` for single-threaded processes and errors for multithreaded processes! (There's also some harder cases with user namespaces but I don't think they're needed)

On Linux, SELinux's `setcon(3)` is guaranteed to fail for multithreaded processes under certain conditions. This requires investigation; it takes some steps to correlate the kernel implementation to userland headers (there is a userland library involved).

From grepping kernel sources those are the only 2 that use specific functions, but there's nothing stopping other functions from being implemented on the same data structures.